# cannot declare struct member within a structure in c

Tags: c, struct

I want to declare a structure value in a different structure definition in header file. So I have done the following in header file. But compiler gives me the error message `field myStructMember has incomplete type`

in A.h header file:

```
struct My_A{
    int value;
};
```

In B.h header file:

```
struct My_A; // forward declaration
struct My_B
    {
        struct My_A myStructMember; // error is here!
        int differentValue;
    };
```

Is it possible to declare a struct member within a structure declarations?

**EDIT:** My_A and My_B are declarated in different header file.

**EDIT 2:** 
When I add include "A.h" in B.h, then it works. Does it make any problem?
In B.h header file:

```
include "A.h" // added this line insead of forward declaration
struct My_B
    {
        struct My_A myStructMember; // not any error anymore
        int differentValue;
    };
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY please see my edit. they are in different header files.

Comment: yeah, thats not gonna work. you could make `myStructMember` dynamic (a pointer) and manage the appropriate allocation in your .c file code, however.

Comment: @WhozCraig see my second edit. Can i use this approach?

Comment: @"see my second edit. Can i use this approach": Yes. Just make sure that you don't end up in race, when including 2 files in one-another. (Happens some times by mistake..)

Comment: That should work, just be careful about a circular include set (i.e. a includes b includes a..., which I think was what @anishsane was trying to say).

Comment: You can't use the structure because it's forwarded and hence the compiler does not know how to allocate the containing structure.  Just like you can't declare a forwarded struct as a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without # including `A.h` in `B.h` (or before `B.h` every time it is referenced - when the compiler parses `My_B` otherwise it lacks the information required to determine the size of `My_A`. You could use a pointer instead, but that gains all the overhead of handling them.

If you are just trying to achieve abstraction / details hiding, then you could change your forward declaration of `My_A` so that it is now a struct of the correct size (using a char array, for instance). Then you must make sure that nothing includes both `A.h` *and* `B.h` as that will cause a compiler error. Oh, and *really* make sure you get the size right or weird stuff will happen. There are ways to ensure this is correct using macro assertions.

e.g. make `B.h`

```
struct My_A{
    char hidden_data[4];
};

struct My_B
{
    struct My_A myStructMember; 
    int differentValue;
};
```

Comment: Yes. See the first sentence of my answer. Downside is that you will always include all of `A.h` wherever you include `B.h` (which you might not want to).

Answer (score 1):

The error is what it says - you can't use struct until you has it's complete type. You simply don't know its size at that point. Forward declaration won't help here.

Alternatively you can use pointer to struct. Pointer size is known.

Comment: When I add include "A.h" in B.h it seems it works! Otherwise I guess I would have to use pointer insead. @aragaer See my edit2